# Flutter: Positioning multiple widgets or images

Tags: flutter, dart

I am relatively new to flutter and I am learning as I go. I want to achieve exactly as the image below. All the components in the image, such as the car, the outlined city and the background shape are in seperate png files. I will have to combine them all to get the result.

[image]

Comment: Can you share those images?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @MendelG The images are: the taxi, the drawing/outline of buildings and the shaped background. So far I have tried using Stack() and then wrapping the image around a Container and use Alightment(x, y), but nothing.

Answer (score -1):

One of the most convenient way to achive this in flutter is to use the Stack widget.
Import your png-s as assets to your pubspec file (more about this here https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/assets-and-images),
then fill up your stack with your images and position them
similar to this example.

```
Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    Positioned(
        top: y,
        left: x,
        child: Container(
          height: h,
          width: w,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage('assets/images/<imagename>.png'),
              fit: BoxFit.<x>,
            ),
          ),
        )),
      Positioned(
        top: y2,
        left: x2 ,
        child: Container(
          height: h,
          width: w,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage('assets/images/<imagename>.png'),
              fit: BoxFit.<x>,
            ),
          ),
        )),
  ],
)
```

More details about Stack(https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html)

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)